# How to use SQL to add a column of data to a result table, that is based on a logical reference within the same table?

Tags: sql

I am trying to add a column to some results not editing the database itself, for the sake of a dashboard program that will be more user friendly, in order to help organize results according to employee supervisors. The supervisors will not know their Employee ID off the top of their heads, and for ease of use, just having their names be the item that is sortable going forward would be useful.

So I want to write a query that will transform TABLE 1 into TABLE 2.

### **TABLE 1**

```
EmployeeID  |  Name  |  SupervisorID | 
1           | Dave   |  3            |
2           | Jeff   |  3            |
3           | Cindy  |  4            |
4           | Carol  |  NULL         |
```

---

### **TABLE 2**

```
EmployeeID  |  Name  |  SupervisorID | **SupervisorName
1           | Dave   |  3            |  Cindy
2           | Jeff   |  3            |  Cindy
3           | Cindy  |  4            |  Carol
4           | Carol  |  NULL         |  NULL
```

Comment: What queries have you tried?  Table 1 is a real table, your employee list?  What is it called?  Then you have a list of supervisors not mentioned, what's it named?  You want to join the two tables on supervisor ID.  Do you have any SQL experience and what database are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...

```
select t1.EmployeeID ,t1.Name, t1.SupervisorID, t2.name As SupervisorName
from table1 t1
left join table1 t2 on t1.SupervisorId = t2.EmployeeID
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/093092/2) in case OP wants it.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the prompt assistance.